# Rebase branch and descendants

Tags: git, rebase

After running `git remote update` I have this structure.

```
      @-@ feature1
     /
o-o-@ master
  |  \
  |   @-@ feature2
   \
    0-0 origin/master
```

Then I run

```
git checkout master
git pull --rebase
git checkout feature1
git rebase master
git checkout feature2
git rebase master
```

and the final tree looks like this

```
          @-@ feature1
         /
o-o-0-0-@ master
         \
          @-@ feature2
```

Is there a quicker way to do this type of rebase, where a commit and any of it's descendants are moved as one?

Comment: You are right, that answered my question.